# i am facing "AttributeError: module 'syft' has no attribute 'VirtualWorker'" for "# Create VirtualWorkers hook = syft.VirtualWorker(hook, id="hook") "

Tags: federated-learning, pysyft

i am facing "AttributeError: module 'syft' has no attribute 'VirtualWorker'" for "# Create VirtualWorkers hook = syft.VirtualWorker(hook, id="hook") "

## Create VirtualWorkers

`your text`hook = syft.VirtualWorker(hook, id="hook")
your text`bob = syft.VirtualWorker(hook, id="bob") your text`alice = syft.VirtualWorker(hook, id="alice"`

i first tried using

## Create a PySyft hook

`your text`hook = syft.TorchHook(torch)`

## Create virtual workers

`your text`bob = syft.VirtualWorker(hook, id="bob")
your text`alice = syft.VirtualWorker(hook, id="alice") your text`but it was depricated so i used this approach `